# How to avoid race updating postgres.JSONField in Django?

Tags: django, postgresql, race-condition

Using Django I learned to use `F` object to mitigate race conditions when updating values on a model.

Now I have a bit more complex problem - I have a model using PostgreSQL's JSONField and I want to update a value contained within the field. I tried doing something like this:

```
year = arrow.utcnow().date().year
my_model.stats['views'][year] = F('stats__%s' & year) + 1
```

Unfortunately an error pops up: `TypeError: Object of type 'CombinedExpression' is not JSON serializable`

I understand it can be done by using some intermediate models to simulate JSON structure but it is out of question here. So the problem is as in title - how to do this in Django? If not possible, what SQL syntax would do that?

Comment: why aren't you using select_for_update in django

Comment: @amrit good point, I'll check how that behaves in my case. Thank you.